# Wrong User Id get in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

After User Login my site got Wrong User ID (Only get Super User ID).

My Code is :

```
$user_id = \JFactory::getUser()->id;
```

Comment: This code gives you id of currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Update My site PHP Version. (Old Version 5.4 to New Version 5.5). In Cpanel Disable Directory Protection. Its Working Good